# How to access a method in SKScene From UIViewController

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I show **UIAlertController()** using NSNotificationCenter from the **SKScene**.

Then when one of the options is clicked to execute method in **SKScene()**. The method will add a node, but if I use

```
let s = GameScene()
s.methodName()
```

This doesnt use the current reference, but creat a new scene and the node is not added

If I pass the Scene when sending the notification like so

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("detectNot", object: self);
```

After given option is chosen and the method is execute it gives an error, there is no info about the error

Answer (score 1):

Send the notification like this

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("detectNot", object: self);
```

In the UIViewController method

```
let _scene = notification.object as! GameScene
```

Then you can access any method